# How to use `package_data` to include files in a PyPi package

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to understand how I can use `package_data` in my `setup.py` to package my data correctly for a private pypiserver. My folder structure looks like this:

```
.
└── elastic-manager/
    ├── elastic_manager/
    │   ├── icons/
    |   |   └──icon.svg
    │   └── lib/
    │       ├── acc/
    │       │   ├── elastic/
    │       │   │   └── query/
    │       │   └── mapping/
    │       ├── views/
    │       └── widgets/
    │           └── json_tree/
    │               ├── edit/
    │               └── input/
    ├── dist/
    └── setup.py
```

I'm trying to include the icons under the `icons`-folder. The following is the contents of my `setup.py`:

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="elastic-manager",
    version="0.0.6",
    description="A graphical application to manage Elasticsearch.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        "elastic_manager": ["icons/*"]
    },
    install_requires=[
        "PyQt5>=5.12",
        "pytz>=2019.1",
        "pyYAML>=5.1",
        "numpy>=1.16",
        "simplejson>=3.16",
        "elasticsearch>=7.0"
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: Non-permissive",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

When I package it using `python3 setup.py sdist` and install it using `pip3` from the generated `tar.gz` I can start the program, but the icons are not included! What am I getting wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `package_data` is for binary dists only (eggs, wheels). It is a no-op when packaging source dists. You should record the data in `MANIFEST.in`, for example via line `include elastic_manager/icons/*`.

Comment: You're right! I found it very unclear what the difference between package_data and MANIFEST.in was!

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood the purpose of `package_data`. I was supposed to create a `MANIFEST.in` in the root as specified by the guide here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#manifest-in

To include everything under the icons folder, I had to add the line `include elastic_manager/icons/*`.

Thanks @hoefling